# Adding a TableView to a UIViewController shows[__NSCFConstantString size] error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am adding a `tableView` to a `viewController` which has custom size ie I am defining its frame.
I haven't set its delegate since I don't want the tableView to perform any actions .even if I set it , the errors are the same.Now this `tableView` is populated by an `array` of images .When I run the app it throws the[__NSCFConstantString size] exception.

Here is what I am doing

[image]

This is the tableView datasource defined in `viewDidLoad`.

```
    menuArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"icone_what1c.jpg",@"icone_what3c.jpg", @"icone_what2c.jpg",@"icone_what4c.jpg" ,nil];
```

And `tableView` datasource methods.

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
       return [menuArray count];
  }


  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
      if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   }

      cell.imageView.image = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      return cell;
   }
```

And this is the summary of the exception.

```
    [__NSCFConstantString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e25c
   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e25c'
     *** First throw call stack:
    (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x01ce85e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018d88b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01d85903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x01cd890b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x01cd84ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   UIKit                               0x0059343f -[UIImageView setImage:] + 389
6   AirMapp                             0x0000f187 -[MainViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 375
7   UIKit                               0x0052cd2f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 412
8   UIKit                               0x0052ce03 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
9   UIKit                               0x00511124 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2378
10  UIKit                               0x005245a5 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
11  UIKit                               0x004a8dd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line

```
cell.imageView.image = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```